# Is it legal to purchase Kaplan IT Training bundle by more than one people? If it is legal, how many people can use it at the same time?

Tags: software

We're planning to purchase [this](https://www.kaplanittraining.com/certification/microsoft/mcsa-windows-server-2016) bundle from Kaplan IT Training by people more than one.

However, firstly, we want to know this kind of purchase is legal or not.

And if it is legal, how many people can use it at the same time?

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [Terms and Conditions](https://www.kaplanittraining.com/terms-and-conditions) page on Kaplan's site:

> Shared use of product is prohibited.

So **no**, you can't do what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

motosubatsu suggests NO, since the Terms and Conditions forbid it.

This is complicated by the First Sale Doctrine, which **overrides** any Terms and Conditions. Since the T&C's do not accurately describe the nature and form of the product, it is hard to establish whether the First Sale Doctrine would apply. If this is written material (e.g. a book), then the First Sale Doctrine applies. But if it's access to an online website, then this product is a service, and the First Sale Doctrine does not apply.

However, the bundle appears to include an exam part, and that exam certainly is not covered by the First Sale Doctrine. You obviously cannot have multiple people take the same exam.